# Developing Ubuntu Phone apps using .NET through Monodevelop

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, monodevelop, dotnet

I would like to know whether Ubuntu for Phones support developing apps using .NET (created through MonoDevelop) as we can do it for Ubuntu Desktop.

Thanx and Regards
Uday Gupta

Answer (score 0):

No, ubuntu phone is not yet supported in mono. AFAIK ubuntu don't have any plan to create official monotouch for ubuntu phone. So the answer is #No    untill some one creates it